flink HA by Kubernetes exception: Operation cannot be fulfilled on configmap；the object has been modified
I deployed flink and provided jobmanager high availability by Kubernetes, but it restart sometimes.
Here are my settings and logs:
jobmanager.rpc.address: flink-jobmanager
high-availability.type: kubernetes
kubernetes.cluster-id: feeyo-pro-flink-001
cluster.registration.initial-timeout: 2000



what should i do to slove this problem

the flink version is flink:1.19.1。the deployment is standalone with k8s。when i said it restart sometimes it means jobmanager application re-election,it looks like it failed to renew k8s lock or some other. jobmanager`s replicas: is 1

do you change your configMap manually? how do you install the operator into your cluster? how is the operator webhook configured?
can you list all settings you defined? what is operator version?
when you asked it restart sometimes do you mean K8sDeployment restarts ? - in this case it is totally normal and your job should take state of your previous job (of course if you set property job.upgradeMode = 'last-state')
unless you mean FlinkDeployment restarts - in this case it is treated as a newly created job.

I'm sorry for the unclear description。the flink version is flink:1.19.1。the deployment is standalone with k8s。when i said it restart sometimes it means jobmanager application re-election,it looks like it failed to renew k8s lock or some other. jobmanager`s replicas: is 1。and here is my configMap
jobmanager.rpc.address: flink-jobmanager
web.upload.dir: xx
high-availability.type: kubernetes
kubernetes.cluster-id: xx
taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 2
blob.server.port: 6124
jobmanager.rpc.port: 6123
taskmanager.rpc.port: 6122
queryable-state.proxy.ports: 6125
parallelism.default: 1

The log is :Message: Operation cannot be fulfilled on configmaps "feeyo-pro-flink-001-cluster-config-map": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again. Received status: Status(apiVersion=v1, code=409...
